# How to make a YouTube embedded video a full page width one?

Tags: html, css, youtube

Here's the fiddle to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/dLPa8/

If you scroll down, there's a video embedded from YouTube. What I need it, it should cover the full page height and width. I mean it should appear somewhat like the first section (in the fiddle).

I tried this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youraddress.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

It solved the problem to a certain extent, but the video clings to the top of the page using the above `iframe`. How can I make the video section height the full page height?

Comment: This guy wrote a good tutorial for responsive youtube vids http://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/

Comment: The full page you means whe WHOLE page? Like a full screen?

Comment: Yup. Kind of full screen.

Comment: 1 page means one 1920x1080 (or 1366x768 or any other) box

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/eFLqJ/)

```
<iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/5iiPC-VGFLU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


$(function(){
  $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });

  // If you want to keep full screen on window resize
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  });
});
```

Comment: To remove the scrollbar just use `body { overflow: hidden; }` or `body { overflow-x: hidden; }` to keep vertical scrolling if you have more elements on the page. I've updated the Fiddle.

Comment: How to make this ONLY adapt to the width and not the height, but still keep the ratio?

Answer (score 1):

Correct style for your iframe

```
iframe {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `innerHeight` or `.clientHeight`:

```
var doc = document, bod = doc.body, dE = doc.documentElement;
var wh = innerHeight || dE.clientHeight || bod.clientHeight;
```

`var wh` now contains window height, without scrollbar.