# URL syntax for Youtube video in fullscreen and start at time index

Tags: youtube, fullscreen

I am able to modify a standard youtube link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0tHEJl_Y8E

to play in fullscreen mode:

https://www.youtube.com/v/R0tHEJl_Y8E

I would like to augment the fullscreen URL so that it starts at time index.  I looked at other [examples](http://www.labnol.org/internet/linking-to-a-specific-time-of-youtube-videos/5101/) and unsuccessfully tried:

https://www.youtube.com/v/R0tHEJl_Y8E&/#t=68s

Suggestions are appreciated: thank you

Comment: The solution for this problem is not here (!), see solution at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22431385/287948

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the YouTube API [Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) page, the `/v/` style URL was used for the embedded AS3 player and is deprecated.  Instead, use `https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID`, with the `start` parameter, e.g.:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/R0tHEJl_Y8E?start=68

Also, just to clarify, this URL will take up the full *browser window*, not the full *screen*.

---

A better solution using `iframe` [here with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22431385/287948) or [simplest here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22431385/287948):

If you add '?rel=0&autoplay=1' to the end of the url in the embed code (like this)

```
<iframe id="video" 
 src="//www.youtube.com/embed/5iiPC-VGFLU?rel=0&autoplay=1"
 frameborder="0"
 allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

of the video it should play on load. Here's a demo over at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/eFLqJ/).

Comment: This works great as long as the URL is youtube.com but when youTube provides a redirect link like youtu.be/VIDEO_ID the redirect fails if /embed is inserted.  However, if you use the same Video_Id that was provided with the redirect link and append it to the youtube.com/embed/Video_Id The video plays in full screen as desired.  But is this valid to change the domain from youtu.be to youtube... or will it break in the future?

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a live stream link?

Answer (score 6):

you can the url for fullscreen

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/R0tHEJl_Y8E?start=68&fs=1

'fs=1' ==> for full screen button to show
'start=68' ==> 68 is in seconds
'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'--> this will enables the fullscreen mode
```

Comment: Nice!  Is a link to a reference available?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/embed/R0tHEJl_Y8E?start=68&fs=1 , this video link is working

Comment: `fs=1` only sets the fullscreen button to display on the player, and is the default value - it doesn't actually affect whether the video is fullscreen. See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#fs

Comment: Even with `fs=1`  **no** full screen button is showed.

Comment: In 2020, adding "&fs=1" to the url breaks the video.

Comment: in 2020 adding "&fs=1" did not break the video but it also did not make the video fullscreen onload. it tells the api if the fullscreen button should be available or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on you chose video, it will show an option saying "Copy URL at current time". This copies a URL that starts at your selected period.

Answer (score 0):

I got newer youtube live stream videos working with this format:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/OWbI6WtlI-k?rel=0&autoplay=1
```