# YouTube iframe cannot go full screen

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

Youtube used to work fullscreen on my site, but a few weeks ago (i think?) it started saying "Youtube cannot go full screen".

I got the code snipped from my site here. And it works in here:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GNBNH5E3ZCPS

Any idea why it wont work on my site? Its exacly the same code.
The site i mentioned is [www.contribee.com](http://www.contribee.com) (scroll down a bit for the iframe video)

Also on a side note: it dose go fullscreen on a mobile browser. But it wont work on desktop Chrome (it does work on w3 editor from any browser)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the fullscreen = true; and call a function
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72689?visit_id=637480296059280325-3361042641&rd=1

`<iframe id="video" src="Source" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Already tried that.

Adding fullscreen = "true" makes the fullscreen button white instead of grey, but it still gives me the error "Full screen mode is disabled"

Comment: Then try just allowfullscreen and according to the document recently all embeds have fullscreen disabled by default

Comment: This may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429866/embed-youtube-videos-that-play-in-fullscreen-automatically