# Embed video programmatic js fullscreen button

Tags: javascript, youtube, html5-fullscreen

So I hide my embed youtube video controls:

```
var player = new YT.Player('player', {
  playerVars: {
    controls: 0,
    showinfo: 0,
    modestbranding: 1,
    autohide: 1,
    iv_load_policy: 3,
    rel: 0
  }
});
```

But I still can open make the video full screen by double-clicking the video, which is fine.

Actually, I'd also like to have a custom button to make the player full screen.

I could actually make the `iframe#player` [full screen](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/), or [use one of these strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182409/how-to-make-a-youtube-embedded-video-a-full-page-width-one) but I'd much rather have a *native* way to do it, which means actually calling the method that is called on a double click on the video.

Any chance I can do that? The doc doesn't seem to talk about it explicitly, and inspecting the `player` JS var did not give me much success either.