# How to remove black borders of youtube embed video from <iframe>?

Tags: javascript, css, html, iframe, youtube

I tried making the youtube embed video's right and left black borders using `<iframe/>` to disappear but it still does not, and tried looping with `loop=1` and does not loop either.

I wouldn't mind the video itself going off screen, preferably contained inside the screen without borders. I just want the visual itself to fully cover the screen and have the black borders on left and right to disappear, and also put it on loop as well.

[image]

What could I be doing wrong?

**Here is the code:**

```css
.nonClickingContainer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.catVideo {
  height: calc(100vh + 50px);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div className="nonClickingContainer">
  <iframe className="catVideo" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7WZPysRdP8A?autoplay=1&autohide=0&controls=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: what are the pixel dimensions of your screen?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry but how do I determine it?

Comment: You can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182409/how-to-make-a-youtube-embedded-video-a-full-page-width-one .

Comment: @LyManeug - magnifying glass and patience - or screen.availWidth screen.availHeight in javascript ... chances are you will get black bars of some sort, unless the available aspect ratio is the same as the video aspect ratio

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry but I am not quiet get what you are saying. Could you show an example?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this link [How to make a YouTube embedded video a full page width one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182409/how-to-make-a-youtube-embedded-video-a-full-page-width-one). If you don't understand just Add a ID to your iframe something like video

```
<div className="nonClickingContainer">
   <iframe id="video" className="catVideo" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7WZPysRdP8A?autoplay=1&autohide=0&controls=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

and then add this JavaScript code to your JS file

```
$(function(){
$('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });

$(window).resize(function(){
$('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  });
});
```

and remove those css code from your css file

```
.nonClickingContainer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.catVideo {
  height: calc(100vh + 50px);
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Sorry I forget to tell you that you need to call jQuery if you not already called it.

Comment: Sorry but what do  you mean by `add remove` and what do you mean by `just Add a ID`?

Comment: sorry I want to say remove your css code. add a id name  your  iframe tag just like below in our case we add id name video  <iframe id="video" className="catVideo" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7WZPysRdP8A?autoplay=1&autohide=0&controls=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: which is use in our JS file to calling iframe tag

Comment: I am using ReactJS. Where should I include the JavaScript code?

Comment: I am not familiar with reactjs. But you can create a js file something like app.js and put those code in that file. I hope it will work. also don't forget to call that file in your main html file

Comment: Sorry I forget to tell you that you need to call jQuery to if you not already called it. Because those JS code written in jQuery